# Best way to protect javascript code from working with modified parameters array

Tags: javascript, arrays, passwords

There is a new javascript game.

Programmatically the game consists of:
already obfuscated javascript code
and
big javascript array with a lot of objects and values (several arrays for several levels)

The problem: 
anybody can get this "already obfuscated javascript code" and change parameters of this "big javascript array with a lot of objects and values" and the game will works in a new manner.

Question:
what can I do to force this "already obfuscated javascript code" to work only with "big javascript array with a lot of objects and values", created by me? 
For example the values of this array/object (generally numbers) should have some "secret" to satisfy a given condition of my javascript - what the "secret" it may be?
Or please offer some additional decision?

I understand, that it impossible to solve completely, but I need nice particular decision, it would be better more than one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A determined user will ALWAYS be able to work around any "security" you try to create.  A dedicated user will always be able to obfuscate anything you write.

There are techniques to make this slightly harder, like making a checksome of your objects, then you pass that object and checksome around ... see if anyone has fiddled with the object behind your back.

A dedicated hacker could then calculate a new checksome.

This cat-and-mouse game has been going on with game binaries for DECADES.. at least three decades and they have proven ineffective them.

They will be less-so today.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should first look into the basics of Javascript programming.

Both [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript):

[image: Codecademy Screenshot javascript course]

and [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp):

[image: W3 SChools Screenshot javascript into]

provide excellent tutorials that teach you how to use javascript.

In terms of how you described how a game works:

> Programmatically the game consists of: already obfuscated javascript code and big javascript array with a lot of objects and values (several arrays for several levels)

Is part of how one section of a game might work. But by no means is it all of what a game is made of...

An array could be used to do any number of things from storing location data, to keeping a list of high scores.

I think to get a better understanding of how a game is made you should look into the fundamentals of javascript first!

If you learn enough you may be able to make your own game!

Best of luck!

Comment: :) hm.
I've already made this game by my own (and know JavaScript, but not a guru).
The architecture of my game is javascript-file and "big array with objects and values", new array for every new level.

But finally I see, that my game may be stolen even with obfuscated JavaScript and new levels of game may be created very easy by changing values in this "big array with objects".